# js: How to enclose these append()s in a div together?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have some js that attaches prev/next links to a bunch of tabs on a page:

> ```
>   $("fieldset.vertical-tabs-pane:not(':first')").append("<a href='#' class='previous-tab' title='Go back to previous step'>< Back</a>");
>     $("fieldset.vertical-tabs-pane:not(':last')").append("<a href ='#' class='next-tab' title='Continue to next step'>Next ></a>");
> ```

I'd like to enclose both links together in one div, so that the final code would read:

```
<div class="navigation">
  <a href>previous</a>
  <a href>next</a>
</div>
```

I am stumped -- I can't just add a `<div>` tag to the first and `</div>` to the last, because the smartness of not showing "back" on the first tab and "next" on the last means that they're not always both there.  I tried enclosing the two lines of js with .after()s that wrote the opening and closing of a div, but it wrote the whole div after the links, not around them.

I'm sure there's got to be a simple solution but I can't figure it out!  Any help is much appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Does this do what you need it to?

```
$("fieldset.vertical-tabs-pane").append('<div class="navigation"></div>');
$("fieldset.vertical-tabs-pane:not(':first') div.navigation").append("<a href='#' class='previous-tab' title='Go back to previous step'>< Back</a>");
$("fieldset.vertical-tabs-pane:not(':last') div.navigation").append("<a href ='#' class='next-tab' title='Continue to next step'>Next ></a>");
```

Comment: Ah perfect!  Make the nav div first, then append to that!  I had to adjust the rest of the code to accommodate the new depth [.parents() instead of .parent()] but now it works exactly as intended.  Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

You can try [`.append()`](http://api.jquery.com/append/) for the last one and [`.prepend()`](http://api.jquery.com/prepend/) for the first one.

Comment: It's my understanding that .append() and .prepend() are for whole elements -- so that if I try to add just an opening div with one of those methods, it opens and closes it for me in one fell swoop.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
var nav = $('<div>', {
   id: 'navigation',
   html: "<a href='#' class='previous-tab' title='Go back to previous step'>< Back</a>\n\
<a href ='#' class='next-tab' title='Continue to next step'>Next ></a>"
});

nav.appendTo($('somewhere'));
```

This is the html that is created:

```
<div id="navigation">
    <a href="#" class="previous-tab" title="Go back to previous step">&lt; Back</a>
    <a href="#" class="next-tab" title="Continue to next step">Next &gt;</a>
</div>
```

Here is a fiddle demo: http://jsfiddle.net/maniator/pb8d5/

Answer (score 0):

Just do this (once you have your links created):

```
$("a.previous-tab, a.next-tab").wrapAll('<div class="navigation"/>');
```

Hope this helps.
Cheers

Comment: That was one of the first things I tried, but it wraps *all* the links into one div -- and there are 8-10 sets of nav links on each page.  So they all showed up together on the first tab. :(